# django pythonforfacebook handle mobile app access?

Tags: python, django, facebook, pythonanywhere

Inspired by the write a facebook app on PythonAnywhere in 20 minutes on Hacker News (http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/35/), I'm writing a facebook app.  All is well with accessing the facebook app via a web browser.  It really did only take me 20 mins...

But, when I access via the facebook iphone app, it complains about no URL for the mobile version.  I then noticed the "Mobile Web" URL in the Facebook App settings page.  I updated the URL and now it at least attempts to get to my website.  But the access is different and it returns a "400 Bad Request" and "missing signed_request"

I gather from a few other questions that there is a difference between these types of facebook apps.  But, since pythonforfacebook handles all of the session work behind the scenes for the canvas app, I'm hoping it can do so with the mobile app.

So, I'm wondering--is it possible for pythonforfacebook to handle the mobile app, too?  What kind of reconfiguration needs to happen to handle both types of access?

Comment: You should have a look at socialregistration.It's a Django app.I've seen that that 20 minutes blog post is also using Django.I've created two Facebook apps using socialregistration and they work flawlessly on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Will do.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few django apps ready-made for this.

the one that stood out from the crowd is **socialregistration** (you can find it at https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) as it supports openID too.

Comment: Okay, well I gave it a go and tried to use this.  I was not very successful.  I need a bit more hand-holding than the extremely terse documentation at that site provides.